# the date completely changes when I change the date column to date format,

Tags: r, type-conversion

I am trying to do a timeseries analysis on a table with a date. The dates range from 1/1/2008 to 2/24/2008. However, when I try to change to date format using `as.date` the dates changes to somewhere in 2020.

```
summary_data$date <- as.Date(summary_data$date, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

The dates are in mdy format. `Summary_data` is the name of my table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (1) `"2/24/2008"` is (I think clearly) "dmy", not "mdy". (2) R displays `Date`-class objects in one format only: `%Y-%m-%d`. If you want to use it as a date (add/subtract days, range of dates, etc) then you need to accept that that least during processing it will be in that format. Once you want to render it into a table, plot, or report, _then_ I suggest you can worry about converting it into what you want with `format(summary_data$date, format="%d/%m/%Y")` (or `"%m/%d/%Y"`).

Comment: With `lubridate::mdy("2/24/2008")` you get `[1] "2008-02-24"`